# Searching by tags in a tag based data base using Java

Tags: java, database, search

Good day everyone,

I am working on a project in Java. In the project I parse a text the user inputs for certain key words. I want to maintain a data base, in which each entry has tags associated to it (much like the tagging system used in this forum). The person who adds the entry is the one who decides which tags are associated to it (it doesn't have to come from an already existing pool of tags).

I never worked with data bases before. What I am looking for are tools which I can work with through Java, which will allow me to create such a database, and would also allow me to search in it using the keywords I parse from the text the user enters.

Does anyone know of such tools?

Answer (score 1):

I have always used SQLite for my databases, as for how to search it, what I would do is create your table with a column for these "tags", then you can easily query this column for the appropriate tags. For information on SQLite and JBDC check out http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/. Oracle's tutorial is also found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You do not mention which database you are going to use, but for relational/SQL databases, the most common API in the Java world is [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity). Most relational databases that support [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) provide a JDBC driver. Using JDBC theoretically allows you to switch to a different database later with minimal or no modifications to your code, as long as you do not use vendor-specific features.

Oracle has a tutorial on JDBC [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).